# Can the Quake games on Steam be modded just as easily as the retail versions?

Tags: steam, mods

Is it possible to use different source engines and mods on the Steam versions of Quake, Quake 2, and Quake 3 Arena?  Are they any more difficult to implement than on the retail, boxed version of the game?

Answer (score 2):

No they are not, you just need to copy the complete game directory to someplace else and do whatever you want to do with it.

I modded Q2 to R1 Q2 and Q3 into CPMA in this way.

i only remember there was a discrepancy of the Steam version of Q3 on where the key file was located, but I do not remember the details at the moment.